# File inside resource folder is not visible for docker file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I have a spring boot application and I am consuming external soap service and I have requirement to put the wsdl file local and I put it in resources folder under wsdl folder. I am reading that file which is inside resources folder under wsdl folder -

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("wsdl/custom.wsdl");
File file = resource.getFile();
wsdlURL = file.toURI().toURL();
```

I have created a simple Dockerfile with below content and running the spring boot application

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/*.jar /app/app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

BUt I am getting below error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [wsdl/custom.wsdl] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/wsdl/custom.wsdl
```

Comment: Try loading the file using: `new ClasspathResource("wsdl/custom.wsdl", getClass())
` **or** `File file = new File(getClass().getResource("wsdl/custom.wsdl").getFile());`

Comment: @CodeDead I tried that but the URL is taking the full path where the class is defined and append "wsdl/custom.wsdl", but it should look into resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, it works inside the docker image also.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;

InputStream inputStream = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("wsdl/custom.wsdl");

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
int i=0;
while((i=inputStream.read())!=-1) {
   sb.append((char)i);
}
System.out.println(new String(sb));
```

In my case, too, I am facing the same issue. Docker image can't find the files in the resource folder, but the above solution solved my issue.